# Is there a method or a way to check whether a user has visited a certain tab page on a QTabWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

I have a QTabWidget on my application, so user can navigate through the tab pages by clicking on the title, I want to know when user open a tab page, whether he/she visited this page previously. In **QWizard** class there is a  method ***hasVisitedPage()*** which does the exact same thing on a wizard, but I couldn't find a similar method in QTabWidget class. What I want to know is, whether there is a method to do this like in QWizard?

this is the similar method in QWizard class http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwizard.html#hasVisitedPage

*Currently I am using a QList to store the visited page indexes and each time when a user open a tabpage check whether QList contains the index of the opened page, I think it would be more easy if I had a method to check*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to know is, whether there is a method to do this like in QWizard?

Unfortunatelly, there is not.

> Currently I am using a QList to store the visited page indexes and each time when a user open a tabpage check whether QList contains the index of the opened page

*QWizard* does the same, i.e. has a `QList<int> history;` attribute. So, in my opinion **you are doing it the right way**.

Take a look at the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qwizard.cpp.html#QWizardPrivate::history) for more details. In particular, [QWizardPrivate::switchToPage](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qwizard.cpp.html#_ZN14QWizardPrivate12switchToPageEiNS_9DirectionE) might be interesting to you, in order to give you an idea how it is done in *QWizard*, so you can check your own implementation against that and adapt it if necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 1):

The `history` property is easy enough to add:

[image: screenshot of the example code]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/tabwidget-history-52033092
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <array>

static const char kHistory[] = "history";

auto getHistory(const QTabWidget *w) {
   return w->property(kHistory).value<QList<int>>();
}

void addHistory(QTabWidget *tabWidget) {
   QObject::connect(tabWidget, &QTabWidget::currentChanged, [tabWidget](int index) {
      if (index < 0) return;
      auto history = getHistory(tabWidget);
      history.removeAll(index);
      history.append(index);
      tabWidget->setProperty(kHistory, QVariant::fromValue(history));
   });
   if (tabWidget->currentIndex() >= 0)
      tabWidget->setProperty(
          kHistory, QVariant::fromValue(QList<int>() << tabWidget->currentIndex()));
}

bool hasVisitedPage(const QTabWidget *w, int index) {
   return getHistory(w).contains(index);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QWidget ui;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&ui};
   QTabWidget tabWidget;
   QLabel history;
   layout.addWidget(&tabWidget);
   layout.addWidget(&history);
   std::array<QLabel, 5> tabs;
   for (auto &l : tabs) {
      auto const n = &l - &tabs[0] + 1;
      l.setText(QStringLiteral("Label on Page #%1").arg(n));
      tabWidget.addTab(&l, QStringLiteral("Page #%1").arg(n));
   }
   addHistory(&tabWidget);
   auto showHistory = [&] {
      auto text = QStringLiteral("History: ");
      for (auto i : tabWidget.property("history").value<QList<int>>())
         text.append(QString::number(i + 1));
      history.setText(text);
   };
   showHistory();
   QObject::connect(&tabWidget, &QTabWidget::currentChanged, showHistory);
   tabWidget.currentChanged(tabWidget.currentIndex());
   ui.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```